# How to edit web.xml context param in Websphere console

Tags: websphere, web.xml, ibm-was, context-param

I have made a web application to be deployed in the Websphere server but i came up with a problem.
I have 20 servlets that use a common parameter so i have this declared on web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>filePath</param-name>
    <param-value>C:\logs.txt</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I want this parameter to be easily edited in the Websphere console but doesn't work. I know this works on Tomcat but is there anything equivalent on websphere?

Thanks

Comment: I just tested this, and it is working fine for me. `String filePath= getServletContext().getInitParameter("filePath");`

Comment: @RamVennam yes it works but what i'm trying to accomplish is to edit the param in the Websphere console.

Answer (score -2):

You should edit web.xml only on the server, there is know interface for it in the Console, as I remember.
You can find this file here:{WAS_ROOT}/profiles/profilename/config/cells/cellname/applications/enterpriseappname/deployments/deployedname/webmodulename

Link to the documentation:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/tweb_jsfengine.html

Comment: that would be ok but the users that will work with this application will not have access to the files of WAS.

Comment: I know that you can use something like this `<servlet>
    <servlet-name>controlServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.jenkov.butterfly.ControlServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
        <param-name>myParam</param-name>
        <param-value>paramValue</param-value>
        </init-param>
</servlet>` and be able to edit on WAS but we are talking about a huge number of servlets with one common parameter. This would´t be ideal.